# NestJS: Type 'NestFastifyApplication' does not satisfy the constraint 'INestApplication'

Tags: node.js, typescript, nestjs, dependency-management, fastify

I'm building a back-end application with NestJS and I'm trying to use fastify instead of express as the underlying framework. I'm following the documentation ([available here](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/performance)) to use fastify, however I got the following type issue:

```
Type 'NestFastifyApplication' does not satisfy the constraint 'INestApplication'.

Type 'NestFastifyApplication' is missing the following properties from type
'INestApplication': use, enableCors, enableVersioning, listenAsync, and 22 more
```

Here the code:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import {
  FastifyAdapter,
  NestFastifyApplication,
} from '@nestjs/platform-fastify';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create<NestFastifyApplication>(
    AppModule,
    new FastifyAdapter(),
  );
  await app.listen(3001);
}
bootstrap();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was simple. Something failed during the installation of `@nestjs/platform-fastify`. Just removing and installing the package was enough to solve

Comment: @ErangaHeshan I know, but Stackoverflow requires me to wait 2 days

Comment: this doesn't solve my issue.

Comment: @Sisir do you have every package correctly installed?

Comment: Yeah, I ended up using express.

Comment: I had the same issue try `npm i`

Comment: Finally found a solution here : https://github.com/nestjs/nest/issues/4036#issuecomment-585790276

Basically ensure that `@nestjs/common`, `@nestjs/core`, and `@nestjs/platform-{express/fastify}` versions in package.json match

Answer (score 0):

PS: If you have the following issue :

```
Type 'NestFastifyApplication<RawServerDefault>' does not satisfy the constraint 'INestApplication'.
```

Perhaps there is a compatibility versions issue of both @nestjs/platform-
fastify and NestJS core packages, so run

```
yarn upgrade-interactive --latest
```

to update the dependencies to their last stable versions.

The ref : https://dev.to/ouelle/basic-crud-operations-with-nestjs-typescript-fastify-mongodb-1f1k